# Procedure running slow in first attempt after migration SQLSERVER 2005 to 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Recently we have migrated SQLServer 2005 to 2012 and seen huge slowness in stored procedures execution.it's taking long time in first attempt but as on expected time in second attempt. I was under impression this may be due to caching but I have used "dbcc freeproccache" but When I'm executing all procedures again they are taking expected time, I don't have seen any performance issue on first attempt to nth times after executing "dbcc freeproccache". To improve the performance

I already did following things which are not working for me.

1. Rebuild the indexes.
2. Updated historic stats using 100% sampling data.

Comment: was there any change in server settings

Comment: Can you capture wait stats when the query is running slow for the first time and compare it ,when it runs second time....query to use `select wait_time,last_wait_time from sys.dm_exec_requests where session_id=your sessionid`

Comment: also when the query runs second time,are you seeing same execution plan

Comment: wait_time   last_wait_type               Attempt
0          SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD 1st
0         MISCELLANEOUS                 2nd /*and execution plan in both cases are same.*/